# How to change list of objects into list of dicts?

Tags: python

I am quite surprised at the behavior of this code, which is inside a function:

```
        for user in full_details["users"]:
            user = collections.defaultdict(lambda: False, user)
            if user["comments"]:
                user["comments"] = [comment.__dict__ for comment in user["comments"]]
                print("just converted user comments to dict objects")
                print(user["comments"])


        print("printing full details")
        print(full_details)
```

My understanding was that if I modified a dictionary or a list, that modification applied to the object and would remain. However, when I change `user["comments"]` for each user in `full_details["users"]` within my `if` I am not then seeing those same changes again reflected in `full_details` just immediately after. Why is that? I thought that whenever you create a new list and assign it to a passed-in parameter, that new list will persist outside the function.

My trouble is that the change made here does not persist:

```
                user["comments"] = [comment.__dict__ for comment in user["comments"]]
```

Also, full_details is a default_dict:

```
full_details = collections.defaultdict(lambda: False, thread_details.__dict__)
```

Comment: Is full_details a normal list or dictionary, or is it some other object like a query set or something else?

Comment: @Monkey full_details is a default_dict: full_details = collections.defaultdict(lambda: False, thread_details.__dict__)

Comment: you're creating a _new_ `user` dict containing a copy of the old one's contents, modifying it, and then throwing it away.  also, i would strongly recommend against "converting" an object to a dict this way — it's invasive, it's not obvious what actually ends up in the dict, and it prevents you from changing how the comment class works internally without breaking these dicts.  i've been here and it's not a fun place to be.

Comment: @EEvee except that from that new user dict I am then making a list in a list comprehension. In the past I have seen list comprehensions as examples of exactly how you should assign to a pre-existing list so I don't follow why it shouldn't work here.

Comment: it has nothing to do with the list comprehension.  you reassign `user`, so you're no longer modifying the dict that's in `full_details`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning "user" twice. First in the for statement. Then in the first line of the body of the for loop, you are creating a new object and also assigning it to "user".  At this point, you have lost your reference to the original object.